# play framework returning views in submodule

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to render submodule view from my submodule controller. But I am getting an error:

```
[error] /home/kd/Application/modules/common/app/controllers/CMS.java:488: error: package views.common.CMS does not exist
[error] return ok(views.common.CMS.UsersView.render());
```

How can I use that view in submodule?
I've tried already:

```
return ok(views.common.CMS.UsersView.render());
return ok(views.common.html.CMS.UsersView.render());
return ok(views.html.common.CMS.UsersView.render());
return ok(views.html.CMS.UsersView.render());
```

but no one works. All the time I am getting an error like:

```
 error: package views.common.html.CMS does not exist
```

When I was doing that in regular app (without modules) it work. I know that is about namespaces, but how can I deal with it. I thought that it will work simillar to the controllers and model where it was f.e.: models.common.SomeClass. But it doesnt work that way.

Comment: Can you post your build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I've accidentally delete view file. And that cause the error.
After setting that file back again, the error dosnt occur anymore.
I think we can close.